# Assign foreign keys only after populating database

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-key, concurrency, parallelism

I am porting a MongoDB database over to a PostgreSQL (relational) database. I would like to perform this task concurrently, and I have developed code with parallelism in mind, but dependencies between tables (foreign keys) are not allowing it. This happens when a row (containing a foreign key) is added, but the table it points to hasn't had that record (primary key) added, throwing the following error:

> ```
> insert or update on table "observernodeoccurrence" violates foreign key constraint "observernodeoccurrence_canonical_id_fkey"
> DETAIL:  Key (canonical_id)=(ba956ef88bcc366fa7d1d5fb696fe98d) is not present in table "canonical".
> ```

This is logical, since the record being added, which contains a FK, is pointing to a record from another table which hasn't been added yet.

*Possible solution*: I thought about a solution consisting of declaring the foreign keys as regular *TEXT* attributes, containing no dependencies to other tables. As soon as the port was completed, those attributes would be converted back to foreign keys. This way, every foreign key would have a record in the destiny table.

Is there a way to achieve this in Postgresql? If not, is there any other thing I can try to achieve parallelism in populating the database?

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**
Use `COPY` from a valid dump of the tables in order to avoid any foreign key conflict (Copy is the fastest way i've found to load bulk data)

**Option 2:**
Create the schema without foreign keys, load the dumps, and recreate the foreign keys after that:
`ALTER TABLE table2 DROP CONSTRAINT fkey;`
`ALTER TABLE table2 ADD CONSTRAINT  fkey; FOREIGN KEY (column_name) REFERENCES table1 (column_name);`

**Option 3:** If you are in a production environment you can try a replication solution, check out how to [create a stream replica from mongo to postgres.](https://github.com/stripe/mosql)

**Option 4:** If you are just trying to migrate some subset or data and keep it sync you can use a connector.

For sure people here can help you with other approaches.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. For now, option 1 and 2 seem viable, I will give them a try. I'm still in early development, I am a researcher for a company.

Comment: I personally recommend option 1, i have restored dumps of hundreds of Gigs in minutes @Khabz

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out. `COPY_FROM` seems the most suitable solution. My doubt is: is the command personalizable enough to be able to extract data out of a list of jsons (mongo) into a table?

Comment: Since I want to export a mongo db into a postgres' I wonder if it's worth converting the jsons into a readable stream and only then copy them into postgres

Comment: Also, I created a dummy database and tried copying content from mongo into a table that references another empty table and it threw the `violates foreign key constraint - not present in table`. How exactly does it `avoid any foreign key conflict`?

Comment: Because you can not add any data that references to an empty table, fill the primary table so you can fill the one with references after @Khabz

Comment: That's exactly the issue I mentioned in the OP. In that case, option 1 and 2 may only complement each other instead of being distinct solutions. In that case, copy doesn't avoid any foreign key conflict.

Comment: If you do copy, table by table, you shoulnd't face any foreign key problem @Khabz